# unexpected problems creating text to png to ico in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, ico

I'm using Python 3.11.4 in Visual Studio Code on Windows 11.
After executing my following Python-Code I receive 2 saved pictures: a png- and an ico-file (`Hello.png` & `Hello.ico`) as expected. But there is something wrong with the files. When I try to rename `Hello.png` (for example to `World.png`), than I receive an `Windows-Errormessage` with the text:

```
"Die Aktion kann nicht abgeschlossen werden, da die Datei in Windows-Explorer geöffnet ist. Schließen Sie die Datei und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang."
```

In English:

```
"The action cannot be completed because the file is open in Windows Explorer. Close the file and try again."
```

But the file is not opened. After restarting Windows, the file can be renamed.

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def generate_png(text):
    # Bild erstellen
    image = Image.new("RGB", (256, 256), (255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # Schriftart und -größe festlegen
    font_size = 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", font_size)
    text_width = draw.textlength(text, font=font)
    bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font=font)
    text_height = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    while text_width < image.width and text_height < image.height:
        font_size += 1
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", font_size)
        text_width = draw.textlength(text, font=font)
        bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font=font)
        text_height = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    font_size -= 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", font_size)
    
    # Text auf das Bild zeichnen
    bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font=font)
    x = (256 - bbox[2] - bbox[0]) // 2
    y = (256 - bbox[3] - bbox[1]) // 2
    draw.text((x, y), text, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)  # fill=(0, 0, 0) -> schwarzer Text

    # Ordner "generierte_Bilder" erstellen, falls er noch nicht existiert
    folder_path = "generated_pics"
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path)
    
    # Bild speichern
    image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f"{text}.png")
    image.save(image_path)
    image.close()

    return image_path

def generate_icon(png_file):
    # PNG-Bild laden
    image = Image.open(png_file)
    
    # Icon-Datei erstellen
    icon = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256))

    # Bildgrößen für das Icon definieren
    sizes = [(16, 16), (32, 32), (48, 48), (64, 64), (96, 96), (128, 128), (256, 256)]

    # PNG-Bild in verschiedene Größen konvertieren und im Icon platzieren
    for size in sizes:
        resized_image = image.resize(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        offset = ((256 - size[0]) // 2, (256 - size[1]) // 2)
        icon.paste(resized_image, offset)

    image.close()

    # Icon als ICO-Datei speichern
    pre, ext = os.path.splitext(png_file)
    icon_file = png_file
    os.rename(icon_file, pre + ".ico")
    icon.save(icon_file, format="ICO")
    
def generate_pic():
    text = "Hello"
    png_path = generate_png(text)
    generate_icon(png_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_pic()
```

When I comment the line

```
generate_icon(png_path)
```

out, than the renaming of the png works fine after executing the code. But the goal is to receive an ico-file.

What changes need to be made to the code so that a png and then an ico file are created from the `text`, but in such a way that after the png file has been created, it can be renamed?